# parse pdf using ruby pdf-reader

Tags: ruby, pdf-reader

I'm trying to parse a pdf using pdf-reader gem. I have explore few methods & display method of specific pdf page shows the correct data (even if table column has more than one line it show that specific column as combined) but it gives the return value as nil so is there any way that we can get the values that this method display ?. Also I have tried to use text method but the problem is that, in the pdf I have table like structure & one table column can have more than one line & due to that reason the text method does not show values in order so it show first row then second row & so on. Therefore it becomes little difficult to judge what specific column has more than one line. Any solution to solve that problem ?

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
reader.page(1).display #display methods print nice pdf data but return nil
reader.page(1).text #display pdf text but does not show value in order (in case of table)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about try below code

```rb
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
puts reader.page(1).display #display methods print nice pdf data but return nil
puts reader.page(1).text #display pdf text but does not show value in order (in case of table)
```

`display`method only print that not return.

if you want see any result. type `puts`or `p` and try

Answer (score 0):

Text in tables might be out of order:

```rb
PDF::Reader.open('my_file.pdf') do |reader|
  reader.pages.each do |page|
    page.text.split("\n").each do |line|
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```